# How can I fix my program with ExecutorService?

Tags: java, executorservice

So, I'm new in Java.

I wrote relatively simple program that does something with a lot of files.

It was slow, I wanted to run more threads than one. With little StackOverflow Community help I made something like this:

```
public class FileProcessor {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // run 5 threads
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
        int i;

        // get first and last file ID to process
        int start = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int end = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);

        for (i = start; i < end; i++)
        {
            final int finalId = i; // final necessary in anonymous class
            executor.submit(new Runnable() 
            {
                public void run() 
                {
                    processFile(finalId);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public static void processFile(int id)
    {
        //doing work here
    }
}
```

This is really really simple multithreading solution and it does what I want. Now I want to fix/improve it because I guess I'm doing it wrong (program never ends, uses more memory than it should etc.).

1. Shall I reduce number of `Runnable` objects existing in memory at the same time? If I should - how can I do it?
2. How can I detect, that all job is done and exit program (and threads)?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reduce the number of threads running, just reduce the size you pass to the fixed thread pool constructor. As for termination, call shutdown and awaitTermination on the executor service. But that will only reduce the number of active threads, not the number of Runnables you're creating in your loop.

Comment: Wait wait... I thought my `for` loop creates 1000000 Runnable objects when program starts and "work" is being processed in background... So... `executor.submit(Runnable)` waits until there is some "free thread"?

Comment: Yes. You created a fixed thread pool, in this case 5. You can submit a million Runnables, but only 5 run at a time. When one finishes, a thread becomes free and the next Runnable is started.

Comment: Well... I know that `Runnable` is started when it should and there is a limit of Runnables started at the same time. But I'm worried about `for` loop that does 1000000 iterations, so I have about 1000000 not started Runnable objects in memory.

Comment: Valid concern. Do a search for articles on how to implement a blocking type executor so that you don't create Runnable objects until a thread is available if you're concerned about having all those objects in memory waiting for a free thread.

Answer (score 0):

when you said `program never ends, uses more memory than it should`, it could be due to many reasons like,

1) `processFile()` might be doing some heavy I/O operations (or) it is blocked for some I/O data.

2) There could be a potential dead lock if there is any common data object share

Your thread logic itself, pretty straight forward with `ThreadPoolExecutor` and I believe the problem is with the code in `processFile()`.

Since you initialized the pool with 5, The `ThreadPoolExecutor` makes sure that there are only 5 active threads doing the work irrespective of how many possible threads you want to create.

So In this case, I would focus more on application logic optimization than thread management.

If you are really concerned about how many `Runnable` objects you want to create? Then That's a trade-off between your application requirement and available resources.

If each thread task is independent and there is a execution time limit for all of those threads, then you create more threads in pool and add more resources.

When you define a `PoolExecutor` with 5 threads at a time limit, and create 10,000 threads then obviously they have to wait as a `Future Task` in memory until a thread is available.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure if it uses too much RAM. My processFile() method is pretty simpl. I'm just confused with big loop that has 1000000 iterations and that `new Runnable()` in that loop. So... there is nothing wrong with my threading code?

Comment: Thread logic looks fine. But if you really want to improve the performance, then Define a class which implements the `Runnable` interface and include the `processFile()` logic inside it. And start `executor` with an instance of that new class.